# Deploy new app version on Beanstalk with Docker and an artifact

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker app running on Elastic Beanstalk, what i want to achieve is to build a compiled version of my app on my CI server, send it to an S3 and then deploy the code to EB.

My dockerfile basically pull the artifact and run it.

What's the best way to push new version of my app with this setup? I run a auto-scaling app with N instances and would like to have as minimum downtime as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EBCLI provides a way to set the [`artifact`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact) to deploy. However, since you cannot pass S3 paths/URLs, you'll need to download the artifact first.

Steps on your CI server, create a script that can:

1. Download artifact from S3
2. `eb init`
3. Programmatically modify `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` so that the `artifact` value is the local path to your artifact.
4. `eb create`/`eb deploy`

Comment: Oh ok, everything in the doc suggest that the artifact should be stored locally (that's what i understand at least). I didn't know we can put a S3 route in it. I'll try, thanks for helping!

Comment: What you read in the docs was right :) . Perhaps, you misread my answer.